# how to bind model to spring from tag radio button to populate list?

Tags: html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to bind  list that is listOftriptransactions to radio button.in my case while update value,after click on radio button value is not get updated,it takes previous value.

```
<table>
<c:forEach items="${listOftriptransactions}" var="trans" varStatus="mystatus">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:radiobutton path="${listOftriptransactions[mystatus.index].isReceived}"   checked="checked" />yes
        <form:radiobutton path="${listOftriptransactions[mystatus.index].isReceived}" checked="checked" />No
</td>  

    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

If there is another solution please let me know.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table>
<c:forEach items="${listOftriptransactions}" var="trans" varStatus="mystatus">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:radiobutton path="listOftriptransactions[${mystatus.index}].isReceived" value="true">Yes</form:radiobutton>
            <form:radiobutton path="listOftriptransactions[${mystatus.index}].isReceived" value="false">No</form:radiobutton>
        </td>  
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```